# Can I specify the radius of each corner of a rounded rectangle?

Tags: c++, direct2d

In Direct2D, rounded rectangle geometry can be created this way:

```
D2D1_ROUNDED_RECT rq = {0};
rq.rect.left = 0;
rq.rect.top = 0;
rq.rect.right = 100;
rq.rect.bottom = 100;
rq.radiusX = 5;
rq.radiusY = 5;

factory->CreateRoundedRectangleGeometry(rq, &geometry);
```

Where `radiusX` and `radiusY` are confusing me, because I can't understand how two values can independently describe 4 (4 rectangle corners radiuses).

Can I set each corner's radius separately like that, or do I need to do it manually using `CreatePathGeometry()` instead?

Comment: This would describe a rounded rectangle where each corner has the same rounded geometry.

Comment: @Eljay, so the only solution - `CreatePathGeometry`? And if this describes all 4 corners at once, why there are two values - `radiusX` and `radiusY`?

Comment: There are two values so you can specify quarter-elliptical geometry for the corners rather than quarter-circular.  (If they are equal, it will be quarter-circular.)

Comment: No you can't you must build a custom geometry using CreatePathGeometry()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/d2d1/ns-d2d1-d2d1_rounded_rect), `radiusX` and `radiusY` are the radii for the quarter ellipse that are drawn in every corner.

You are not specifying the radius for every corner but for all of them at once. When `radiusX` is larger than `radiusY`, it's essentially a rounded rectangle that looks "squished".

---

If the radii are larger or equal to the half size of the rectangle, it'll be drawn like a regular ellipse that you would draw with `D2D1_ELLIPSE`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is code for rounded rectangle with ability to specify each corner separately

```
ID2D1PathGeometry *CreateRoundRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int leftTop, int rightTop, int rightBottom, int leftBottom)
{
    ID2D1GeometrySink* sink = nullptr;
    ID2D1PathGeometry* path = nullptr;

    factory->CreatePathGeometry(&path);
    path->Open(&sink);
    
    D2D1_POINT_2F p[2];

    p[0].x = x + leftTop;
    p[0].y = y;
    sink->BeginFigure(p[0], D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN::D2D1_FIGURE_BEGIN_FILLED);
    p[1].x = x + width - rightTop;
    p[1].y = y;
    sink->AddLines(p, 2);

    p[0].x = x + width;
    p[0].y = y + rightTop;

    if (rightTop)
    {
        D2D1_POINT_2F p2 = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(0, p[1]).TransformPoint(p[0]);
        sink->AddArc(D2D1::ArcSegment(p2, D2D1::SizeF(rightTop, rightTop), 0, D2D1_SWEEP_DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE, D2D1_ARC_SIZE_SMALL));
    }

    p[1].x = x + width;
    p[1].y = y + height - rightBottom;
    sink->AddLines(p, 2);
    
    p[0].x = x + width - rightBottom;
    p[0].y = y + height;

    if (rightBottom)
    {
        D2D1_POINT_2F p2 = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(0, p[1]).TransformPoint(p[0]);
        sink->AddArc(D2D1::ArcSegment(p2, D2D1::SizeF(rightBottom, rightBottom), 0, D2D1_SWEEP_DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE, D2D1_ARC_SIZE_SMALL));
    }

    p[1].x = x + leftBottom;
    p[1].y = y + height;
    sink->AddLines(p, 2);

    p[0].x = x;
    p[0].y = y + height - leftBottom;
    if (leftBottom)
    {
        D2D1_POINT_2F p2 = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(0, p[1]).TransformPoint(p[0]);
        sink->AddArc(D2D1::ArcSegment(p2, D2D1::SizeF(leftBottom, leftBottom), 0, D2D1_SWEEP_DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE, D2D1_ARC_SIZE_SMALL));
    }


    p[1].x = x ;
    p[1].y = y + leftTop;
    sink->AddLines(p, 2);
    p[0].x = x + leftTop;
    p[0].y = y;
    if (leftTop)
    {
        D2D1_POINT_2F p2 = D2D1::Matrix3x2F::Rotation(0, p[1]).TransformPoint(p[0]);
        sink->AddArc(D2D1::ArcSegment(p2, D2D1::SizeF(leftTop, leftTop), 0, D2D1_SWEEP_DIRECTION_CLOCKWISE, D2D1_ARC_SIZE_SMALL));
    }
    
    sink->EndFigure(D2D1_FIGURE_END::D2D1_FIGURE_END_CLOSED);
    sink->Close();
    SafeRelease(&sink);

    return path;
}
```